# How to order a collection and its subcollection using LINQ?

Tags: linq, collections

I have a collection of Employees, and each employee has a collection of Responsibilities.  I would like to output a list of the employees sorted by Name and output their Responsibilities, sorted by Title.

So, it should be outputted like this:

---

Jane Jones

Responsibilities:

Responsibility A

Responsibility B

Mike Smith

Responsibilities:

Responsibility A

Responsibility C

---

To get the initial collection I use:

```
var employees = _context.Employees.OrderBy(e => e.Name);
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to order the Responsibilities subcollection as well.

I'm using MVC and my View receives a strongly typed Employee collection so I don't want to build and return an anonymous type.

Comment: I've decided to not order the colelction when I pull it from the database.  Technically ordering is part of the presentation so I am now doing it in the View (I'm using MVC).  I now am ordering the sub-collection when I do a foreach over employee.Responsibilities.

Comment: Would be nice to know how to do this for future reference though.  Thanks!

Comment: I've added 2nd approach.. Sorry, it's quite heavy too. I don't think there is an easier way, so I agree with you - it would be much better to do ordering in the view or create some special DTO (Data Transfer Object) and do a projection into it and then pass to the view instead of the Employee.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like:

```
var employees = _context.Employees.OrderBy(e => e.Name);
employees.ToList().ForEach(e => e.Responsibilities = e.Responsibilities.OrderBy(r => r.Name));
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error: Cannot convert source type IOrderedEnumerable<> to target type EntityCollection<>.

Comment: Worked for me. I'm not sure it's the best way for my particular case but for now i'll stick with it.

Comment: For someone who is getting error as 'Cannot convert source type IOrderedEnumerable<> to target type EntityCollection<>'. You'd just convert it to list viz. `employees.ToList().ForEach(e => e.Responsibilities = e.Responsibilities.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList());`

Answer (score 3):

**1st approach:** (*is only suitable for LINQ to Objects with Responsibilities defined as IList*)

You could copy into a new collection of Employees but this means that you need to re-copy each field into new employee, something like this:

```
var employees = from e in _context.Employees
                orderby e.Name
                select new Employee
                {
                    Name = e.Name,
                    ...re-assign other properties...
                    Responsibilities = e.Responsibilities.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList()
                };
```

**2nd approach:**

Using the [DataLoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx). Basically, you create a DataLoadOptions object which specifies how to order a particular relationship, so in your case:

```
var options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.AssociateWith<Employees>(e => e.Responsibilities.OrderBy(r => r.Name));
_context.LoadOptions = options;

var employees = _context.Employees.OrderBy(e => e.Name);
```

The Responsibilities will be ordered automatically.

Comment: I too think it is a waste to recopy each field.  In reality, when I try this I get an error that I cannot cast an object of IQueryable to EntityCollection.  So this doen't work for me.

Comment: yeah, it needs to be converted to EntitySet vs List.. plus you can't create a new Employee within the query b/c L2S doesn't allow that, so it appears that only 2nd option can be used in your scenario.