# Ordering a c# list by displayorder and siblings

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Forum
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public String Title { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public Int32 DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsLocked { get; set; }

    public Int32? ParentForumId { get; set; }

    public virtual Forum ParentForum { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Forum> Subforums { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting a `List<Forum>`. I am looking for a way to display it properly in a view so I set up a model that is supposed to put the items in a proper order but I do not know where to start.

The items need to be ordered by displayorder and children. Example:
Forum 1
-- Subforum 1 
---- Subsubforum 1 
-- Subforum 2 
-- Subforum 3 
---- Subsubforum 1 
---- Subsubforum 2
etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to order a collection and its subcollection using LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455695/how-to-order-a-collection-and-its-subcollection-using-linq)

Comment: I might be missing something here @stuartd but I don't see how that would be of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a list of `Forum` objects without any hierarchy. Just pass it to `Reorder` method.

```
 List<Forum> FormHierarchy(List<Forum> allForums) {
     foreach(var forum in allForums) 
         forum.Subforums = allForums.Where(x => x.ParentForumId == forum.Id)
             .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList();
     return allForums.Where(x => !x.ParentForumId.HasValue)
         .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList();
 }
```

After `Reorder` will be executed a list of root forums which don't have any parent will be returned.

Comment: @Angelika S Michel, so you don't have it extracted yet, right?

Comment: Extracted what? I have a list of forums without the virtual properties.

Comment: @Angelika S Michel, I mean you don't have to deal with entity framework any more. You have only `List<Forum>` and you what to convert it into hierarchy with metioned sorting. Right?

Comment: No, I do not have access to the DAL. I cannot deal with EF. And yeah, I would like to convert it to the hierarchy mentioned.